# How to count the number of ROWS in SQL table

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

i have two tables. First table (Class) is table in which there are classes which student can choose, and last column(numberOfRegistration) is the number of registration per class. Here is the first table:

```
idClass int;
name varchar(50);
date varchar(50);
state bit;
description nvarchar(50);
numberOfRegistration  int
```

Second table (Registration) is for registration:

```
idRegistration  int;
dateOfRegistration  date;
name varchar(50);
lastName varchar(50);
city nvarchar(50);
adress nvarchar(50);
postalNumber int;
idClass int - this is foreign key, references idClass from Class table ;
```

Does anyone have idea how to get the number of registration per class in table Registration , and to write that data into last column(numberOfRegistration) in table Class.

Thank you

Comment: This seems like a bad database design. Don't store values that are easily computed. In this case, `select idClass, count(*) from Registration group by idClass` would give you the number of registrations per class.

Comment: Ok. I need to fill gridview with following data:

Comment: Ok. I need to fill gridview with following data: classname, numberOfRegistration. My idea was to join data from class table and count(*) from Registration table, and to present it in gridview. i tried this query: 
SELECT name, COUNT(idRegistration) FROM Class LEFT JOIN Registration ON class.idClass=registration.idClass GROUP BY idClass but i got this error: Column 'class.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Can you please check what i am doing wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE c
SET numberOfRegistration = COUNT(0)
FROM Class c
LEFT JOIN Registration r ON r.idClass = c.idClass
GROUP BY r.IdClass;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived table to combine the group by results with the class table, like this:

```
SELECT name, NumberOfRegistrations
FROM Class 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT idClass, count(*), NumberOfRegistrations 
    FROM Registration 
    GROUP BY idClass
) D ON class.idClass = D .idClass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think building two steps for a complete solution.
First step is updating the Class table with current values as a starting point.
As second step, you can create a SQL trigger to keep the registration counts up to date for the related class

Here is an Update script for first step

```
update class 
set numberOfRegistration = cnt
from class c 
left join (
    select r.idClass, COUNT(r.idRegistration) cnt
    from class c
    left join Registration r on c.idClass = r.idClass
    group by r.idClass
) t on c.idClass = t.idClass
```

And this is the SQL trigger code. I created the [sample SQL trigger](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) as After Insert, Update, Delete trigger as seen in below code

```
Create TRIGGER dbo.Registration_changes
 ON dbo.Registration
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

WITH CTE AS (
    select idClass from inserted
    union all
    select idClass from deleted
), cte2 as (
    select CTE.idClass, COUNT(r.idRegistration) cnt
    from cte 
    left join Registration r on CTE.idClass = r.idClass
    Group By CTE.idClass
)
update Class
set numberOfRegistration = cte2.cnt
from cte2 
where class.idClass = cte2.idClass

GO
```

I hope it helps,

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below query :

```
select idClass, count(*) as [NumberOfRegitsration PerClass] 
from Registration 
group by idClass
```

Comment: select idClass, count(*) as [NumberOfRegitsration PerClass] 
from Registration 
group by idClass - i only miss name from Class table. How can i joint together with this data.

Comment: For this please refer the below query :
select C.id,C.name,r.[NumberOfRegitsration PerClass] from Class C left join (
select idClass, count(*) as [NumberOfRegitsration PerClass] 
from Registration 
group by idClass) R 
on c.idclass=r.idclass